# "Error: failed to write, posix_fallocate failed: ENOTSUP (Operation not supported on transport endpoint)" when installing APK on Android-x86

Tags: installation, apk, android-x86

So, I've been wanting to play PUBG for a while now, but my PC is pretty awful, then Mobile came out, and TGB didn't work properly. I've been trying out several different Android OS, but all of them need a processor that supports SSE4.2+.

So, I checked out this Android-x86 OS, the 32-bit version (the first one that booted, I'm pretty sure that the game wouldn't really work anyway since the version is 32 bits, but I wanted to give it a shot anyway), and well, I can't download anything from the Play Store or install any APK.

I figured out a way to install APK from the terminal, and there I discovered this error:

```
130|x86:/sdcard/Download # pm install
1535771455810.jpg                         Pixel Dungeon_v.1.9.2a_apkpure.com.apk    RAR_v5.60.build63_apkpure.com.apk
130|x86:/sdcard/Download # pm install Pixel\ Dungeon_v.1.9.2a_apkpure.com.apk
Error: failed to write, posix_fallocate failed: ENOTSUP (Operation not supported on transport endpoint)
130|x86:/sdcard/Download #
```

<sup>[Original screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azEDl.png)</sup>

Why can't I install any apps on Android x86?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that the cause is the ext3 partition.

https://github.com/anbox/anbox/issues/108

The problem with this OS is that if you install it on a FAT32/ext4 partition, the grub doesn't work to dual boot with Windows, and if you install in NTFS, it dual boots but you boot without any free space on the OS

So yeah, rip lol